# Getting a type error at Articles/1/:get() got multiple values for argument 'id'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, backend

```
class Article_List(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        articles = Article.objects.all()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self,request):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)  # Bad Request


class ArticleDetails(APIView):
    def get_objects(self, id):
        try:
            return Article.objects.get(id=id)
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def get(self, id):
        article = self.get_objects(id)
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request , id):
        article = self.get_objects(id)
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    def delete(self, request,id):
        article = self.get_objects(id)
        article.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is, provide a traceback, such that other people can later benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `get` is always `request`, even if you do not use the request, so:

```
#                ↓ request parameter
def get(self, request, id):
    article = self.get_objects(id)
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(article)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```